# Plugin for Notepad++ to reformat my html code

Tags: html-editor, notepad++

Somebody sent me something like this code snippet below (i honestly don't know where he learnt coding from)

```
<div class="fl spinner2" style="position: absolute; left: 611.5px; top: 302.5px;"><div class="spinner-container container1"><div class="circle1"></div><div class="circle2"></div><div class="circle3"></div><div class="circle4"></div></div><div class="spinner-container container2"><div class="circle1"></div><div class="circle2"></div><div class="circle3"></div><div class="circle4"></div></div><div class="spinner-container container3"><div class="circle1"></div><div class="circle2"></div><div class="circle3"></div><div class="circle4"></div></div></div>
```

Is there a plugin for Notepad++ that can help me auto-format and indent it appropriately. It will take too long for me format it by hand.

I need it to look like this

```
<div class="fl spinner2" style="position: absolute; left: 611.5px; top: 302.5px;">
<div class="spinner-container container1">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
</div>
<div class="spinner-container container2">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
</div>
<div class="spinner-container container3">
    <div class="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2"></div>
    <div class="circle3"></div>
    <div class="circle4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Errm, shouldn't the second line (`<div class="spinner-container container1">`) and subsequent lines be indented, because you have not yet closed the dive from the first line?

Comment: And, I know that it's not your code, but it's best to use CSS, rather than in-line styling

Comment: that why i had to comment on his coding skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Tidy 2" plugin or the "XML Tools" which both are available in the "plugin manager".

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad

Comment: It only works on 32bit OS.
64 Bit it fails.